# module-info javadoc: @moduleGraph

Tags: java, javadoc, java-module, module-info

The javadoc of the module-info of the JDK 11 modules use the tag `@moduleGraph`.

I guess this is what generates the module graphs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/module-summary.html

Is this a non-standard tag? I can't find any [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html) on this tag and it doesn't work when I add it.

Is there a way to generate this graph?

Comment: Nothing public but you could look into something like `com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleGraphBuilder` to get an idea of how such a graph is built.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a custom javadoc tag only for building the OpenJDK javadocs.

The new @moduleGraph javadoc custom tag was created by [JDK-8173303](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173303). The graph images themselves are created by a tool called [GenGraphs](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/make/jdk/src/classes/build/tools/jigsaw/GenGraphs.java).

You can find more background details at: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-March/011838.html

And at:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176785

And at:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173374